# Ivy trimmings in the bottom of a raised planter

Tags: raised-beds, english-ivy

If I put English Ivy trimmings in the bottom of a raised planter will they grow back and invade it?

I am talking roots as well as the above ground plants.

The plan is to use them as filler underneath soil and compost in the pictured raised planter.

The planter is 40cm deep.

**To be clear I don't want the ivy to grow back.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English Ivy will grow anywhere (at least in the UK, and your profile says you are in London).

If you are trying to save a bit of money by filling the base of the planter with it, don't try that idea!

Comment: Also grows aggressively in US zone 8 and other zones.

Comment: "Aggressively"  isn't really the right word in the UK, but "tenaciously" certainly is. I once gave up trying to kill some ivy that was growing in a 1/4-inch wide crack between a solid concrete driveway and the brick wall of a house. Three years of pulling it out by the roots, and using chemical weed killers, didn't work!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJ7vrpU27PU